# Ctrl-p and Ctrl-n behaving unexpectedly under Docker

Tags: linux, bash, docker

For the life of me I can't seem to figure out why <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> don't work like they're supposed to under the Docker images I have been working with.
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> should work just like the <kbd>up</kbd> arrow but I usually have to press it twice to get the last command I ran. And it cycles through the history in what seems to be a random fashion.

Maybe someone can help me make some sense of this.

```
docker run -it buildpack-deps:trusty # run a Linux based image

root@74cbcf321fae:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  ...
root@74cbcf321fae:/# touch hello
```

If I press <kbd>up</kbd> here, it should show the `touch` command, followed by `ls`.
If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> however, nothing comes up the fist time. When I press it again, `ls` appears magically.

Can someone help me make sense of these. I can't live without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It looks like this has been removed (or moved) in the Docs, but it used to live here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/

**Edit**: It looks like they reference the below in the [Configuration Files](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files) documentation.

The command sequence to detach from a docker container is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd>, which is why <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> doesn't work as expected. When you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>, docker is waiting on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd>, so nothing happens.

You can use the new `--detach-keys` argument to `docker run` to override this sequence to be something other than <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>:

```
docker run -ti --detach-keys="ctrl-@" ubuntu:14.04 bash

$# ls
$# <--- Ctrl-P here will display ls now
$# <--- Ctrl-@ here will detach from the running container
```

If you want, you can add this to your `~/.docker/config.json` file to persist this change:

```
{
    ...
    "detachKeys": "ctrl-@",
    ...
}
```

More details on this can be found here: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15666 as I can't find it in the docs anymore.

Comment: I'm running Docker for Mac and I don't have a ~/.docker directory at all. I can't seem to find my config.json.

Comment: Ok, seems the ~/.docker directory doesn't get created until you use docker login, so it's safe to create it if it doesn't exist. I've got this working under Docker now, however, it's not working under Docker-Compose. Does compose use a different file?

Comment: Hm, `docker-compose` shouldn't make a difference as it connects to the same running docker daemon which is where the config is loaded. I just tested this and it worked under `docker-compose` for me, though I'm not sure if the behaviour is different for OSX.

Comment: This answer made my day. Could not figure this out. Can confirm this fixed my problem and now docker neovim / vim work as expected.

Comment: Pressing `ctrl`-`e` if nothing happens after `ctrl`-`p` helps for the moment if you don't want to change the config for some reason. It's a no-op in this case, just triggering the display.