# kubectl exec ... /bin/bash eating control-p?

Tags: kubernetes, escaping

If I run:

```
kubectl exec spi-tools-dev-3449236037-08pau -it -- /bin/bash
```

I get an interactive shell, but something is eating ^p characters.  If I type one ^p, nothing happens.  When I type a second ^p, two get sent.  In bash, I go two items back in my history.  In emacs, I go up two lines.

What's going on here?  Something is obviously interpreting ^p as a command/escape character, but I don't see anything in the kubernetes docs that talks about that.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820108/ctrl-p-and-ctrl-n-behaving-unexpectedly-under-docker) solves your issue?

Comment: It helps a little.  That's exactly the behavior I'm seeing, but I'm not running "docker attach", I'm running "kubectl exec".  I don't see how to configure this for kubectl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using tmux, adding this line to `tmux.conf` helped me to workaround this issue:

```
bind -n C-p send Up
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the answer is:

1. Yes, this is kubectl's emulation of docker's ctrl-p/ctrl-q detach sequence.
2. No, there's nothing you can do to change it.
3. See [this closed bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79110).

I'm running this under tmux, which in turn is under ssh.  Each of which has their own in-band command signalling.  It's amazing anything works at all :-)